# Interpretation of ouput

Tags: analog, datalogger

I have everything in place to log my consumption of elektricity and water, but have no success to log my gas consumption.
My gas meter is an old mechanical meter with rotating numeric wheels.
There is no reflecting part on one of the wheels. Also there is no magnetic signal that is detectable. I tried already with an IR array sensor.
Now I've placed an IR sensor (diode) + IR led on one of the wheels, and amplified the output with a differential amplifier (with opamp). In the picture, you see the result. There is indeed a pattern. The challenge is now to 'translate' this in 1's and 0's (where 1 is for example the start of a pattern). I like to use the '1' as a signal for a hardware interrupt. Maybe getting the spikes significant higher?
All idea's to solve this, or get another solution are very welcome!
I informed for another gasmeter, but that is expensive...

Wannes

[image: Output signal]

Rough schematic:
[image]

Comment: It would help if you visually correlated the position of the wheel with the graph, so that you could interpret what those repetitions are (full revolutions? Dings/dirt on the wheel? etc..). We have no way of knowing what any of that means. (It doesn't help that the graph doesn't have a horizontal scale, is that months, seconds? the IR could be affected by the sun, and the peaks are just 12h00~)

Comment: This is useless. Use a comparator instead of op-amp. Show your circuit schematics.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. For the graph: 1 pattern is one rotation of the wheel; the lenght of the chart is about 2 minutes. The changings of the Y-value comes from the reflection on the numbers. When the meter stops, it is a straight horizontal line. It is covered, so no influence of daylight.

Comment: I added a rough schematic

Comment: I would try to filter some of the high frequency jittering out by connecting a very small value capacitor between ground and the resistor on the + input leg of the amp/comparator. I would start with 100 to 1000 pf, then work my way up.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the output of your opamp as input to a hardware interrupt, you will have a lot of false triggers.  What you need is to "clean up" as much as possible, the input and output of the IR sensor.
you can start by eliminating **reflections** of the IR diode from triggering the IR detector.  Next, smooth the signal after the IR detector with appropriate **band pass filter**.  Next, use a **debounce** circuit to provide one TTL pulse for each position of the wheel.
There should be no need to use the opamp.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Guill. The reason why I use the ompamp is that the amplitude of the signal is very low. I know how to build a debounce circuit. But I have no experience with filtering such a signal. Maybe a remark is that de frequency of the signal depends strongly of the gas usage. If the gas usage is very low, I still have to find a peak that I can use as the confirmation that the wheel has turned one round.